# How to disable device flow and implicit flow in identity server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 and developing a financial application. I assume that none of the API clients will be using device code flow. And hence as a security good practice, I want to disable it for all clients and hide it in discovery document. I have checked the identity server official document but did not find any resources. so my question is.

1. How can I disable the device code flow grant type for all the clients.
2. How can I hide it in the discovery document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the endpoint:

```
services
    .AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Endpoints.EnableDeviceAuthorizationEndpoint = false;
    })
```

That should also remove it from the discovery document.

Please note that you can't disable flows for clients as you have to explicitly configure the client to use it. In other words, as a client is not configured to use a grant type, it can't use it. No need to disable it in some other way.

If an endpoint is avaiable and visible, then you can't hide the endpoint per client. It is a public document.